# Android instrumentation test involving system apps

Tags: android, robotium, instrumentation, android-testing

I must be missing something obvious here:

I'm running an instrumentation test case on a device, also with the help of Robotium. At some point my app under test causes the default e-mail compose activity to fire.

What I'd like to know is: how do I close that activity so to show back again my app activities? That is needed *at least* for one reason: after current test case completes, the email activity remains in foreground, and this prevents the next test case from running properly.

I tried to send the required back keys to the email activity - with `this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` or `solo.goBack()` - but with no luck.

If I run `solo.getCurrentActivity()` or `this.getActivity()` I get a reference to the *topmost* activity within **my** package, but no way to get a hold of the actual foreground activity. Also, the mentioned `sendKeys/goBack` go straight to my activity, not the email one.

Same problem arises when my app launches the Play Store main activity.
I realise that the email activity is not part of my package under test, and this might be part of the problem.

So, is there a way to close the email ativity?

**Edit**
For now I'm sticking to @Joe Malin first suggestion:

In my ViewModel (or Controller), have a `private static boolean _productionMode = true;`
and have some helper method (better if in some inner helper class) used only during testing:

```
public void dontLaunchExternalApps()
{
  _productionMode = false;
}
```

Then in some ViewModel regular method:

```
if (_productionMode)
{
   launchSomeExternalApp();
}
else
{
   // Do Nothing Or Set Some Internal Flag
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to do it. The Android instrumentation framework is really meant to unit test an Android component. Once control passes out of the component, some other framework has to take over.

Perhaps you can start the initial activity with extended data that tells the Activity to send a stub email Intent instead of the real one. The real problem is not closing the the email Activity, it's *mocking it* so that you get back from it what you expect to get back. Unfortunately, mocking is not supported in Android components. The way around *that* is to delegate most operations to POJO subclasses and then mock them.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I'm already unit testing components, TDD-ing, and also running integration/functional tests. The test I'm talking about is in fact a functional test. 
I understand that your first suggestion is basically to let the activity detect that it's running in test mode, so to not actually start the email composer, but do something else testable from the outside. It might be a way...

Answer (score 1):

You can create an intent filter in your tests to check the correct intent is fired and then handle giving the result back or you can make an app just for testing this, e.g. an app that handles the email intent and set this to the system default, this app can actually have no gui and automatically return the results you want, either hardcoded or based on a file somewhere you can both read or as extra info in the intent even.

Here is an example:

```
//set up the filter
final Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentFilter.addDataScheme("http");
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

//Set up the monitor
//THE BOOLEAN ON THE END TELLS THE SYTEM TO BLOCK IT FROM OCCURING, you probably want true here
ActivityMonitor monitor = inst.addMonitor(intentFilter, null, true);

assertEquals(0,monitor.getHits()); 

//click the link here with whatever framework you are using
solo. clickOnText("link text")

//Wait for the activity to get hit
monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(2000); 

//Here is where you actually check it happened
assertEquals(1, monitor.getHits()); 
inst.removeMonitor(monitor);
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I'm not looking for any result back from external app/activity. 
I should create a whole app (even if simple) just for testing purposes, and that is a little bit too much according to me (already having 3 projects just for testing: Unit, Integration, Functional). Also, I don't like having to manually set this app as default email one. I'd prefer to keep the testing enviroment as simple and as automated as possible.

Comment: If you don't want anything back then you should just create an intent filter in your instrumentation tests. It's like six lines of code and stops you having to put in lots of useless code in your real application.

Comment: uhm. But then, I guess I should manually go on the device and set that instrumentation app as default "handler" for the email intent, otherwise I guess a popup would come up during testing, asking me if I want to open the email app or my intrumentation app. 
Is that right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, have a look at the code i have addded.

Comment: thanks for your input. I didn't know one could prevent an Intent from occurring by means of monitor. I'll give it a go. (BTW: the first chunk of newly added code is missing a newline, so it doesn't come out properly formatted)

Comment: Hey! I know this was asked a log time ago, but im needing to do something similar but preventing an ACTION_SEND intent from happening... Unfortunately, although i correctly set the mime type, the filter is not matching the intent... I think this is due to my custom handling of possible apps that can handle the sharing intent. (I make use of `Intent.setPackage()`)... Is there a way to do this?